# Handling C# Nested Classes in Cassandra

Tags: c#, cassandra

I have a C# class as like below

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
}
```

I created key space and table as below

```
ISession session;
        IMapper Mapper;
    Table<User> table;

    var mapping = MappingConfiguration.Global.Define(
                     new Map<User>()
                    .TableName(typeof(User).Name)
                    .PartitionKey(u => u.UserId))

                    ;

        Dictionary<string, string> replication = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        replication.Add("class", "SimpleStrategy");
        replication.Add("replication_factor", "3");
        var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
                                       .AddContactPoints("127.0.1")
                                       .WithPort(9042)
                                       .WithLoadBalancingPolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("test"))
                                       .WithReconnectionPolicy(new FixedReconnectionPolicy(400, 5000, 2 * 60000, 60 * 60000))
                                       .Build();


        session = cluster.Connect();
        session.CreateKeyspaceIfNotExists("demo1", replication);
        session = cluster.Connect("demo1");


        table = new Table<User>(session, mapping, typeof(User).Name, "demo1");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

I am getting the following error

> Cassandra.InvalidTypeException: 'Unknown Cassandra target type for CLR
>   type Casandra.Address'

Answer (score 1):

Your C# class `Address` should match a field type in your Apache Cassandra database.

In this case, it looks like you would want to use [User-Defined Types (UDT)](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#creating-a-udt). The DataStax C# Driver doesn't support creating nested subtypes with `Table<T>.Create()`.

Ideally, you should define your schema first, that should be modeled against the queries you want to use to obtain the data. I would recommend that you do that first, in CQL and then add the [mapping configuration](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.11/features/components/mapper/#configuring-mappings) in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var mapping = MappingConfiguration.Global.Define(
                     For<User>()
                    .TableName(typeof(User).Name)
                    .PartitionKey(u => u.UserId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, For is in which namespace, I am using CassandraCSharpDriver version 3.11.0.

Comment: Hi, I notice your 
`.AddContactPoints("127.0.1")`
is not a valid IP.

Please change it to 
`.AddContactPoints("127.0.0.1")`
if you are hosting locally